# Creating number pattern with minimum for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, design-patterns, minimum

How to create the following number pattern with minimum for loops. Is there any names given mathematically for the pattern of numbers as like Fibonacci, pascal's triangle, any-other interesting patterns which are complicated but possible using for-loops ?

> Expected O/P Pattern:

```
    1
    22
    333
    4444
    55555
    6666
    777
    88
    9
```

// For loops only prints only from 1 to 5 it prints correctly and on reversing there comes the wrong output.

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
{
for(int j=1,k=10; j<=i&&k>5; j++,k--)   
        {
            if(i<=5)
            System.out.print(i);
            else
            if(i>5)
            System.out.print(i);
        }
            System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: @RandMate you should check my solution, it is generic and simpler to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are:

```
for (int i = 1, j = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++, j = (i <= 5) ? (j*10 + 1) : (j/10))
    System.out.println(i * j);
```

Comment: @RandMate i expect you try my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with a simpler logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * input - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input - Math.abs((input - i)); j++)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You print the elements with respect to the absolute value of their difference from input.
If you change the input to another value this will still work.

Comment: the iteration is understandable than the previous one, which model of code is efficient by the way,

Comment: Sergei's answer uses 1 loop, but mine uses 2 loops. So for bigger numbers of input (in our case it's 5) his code will run faster, I guess. anyway, you can upvote my answer if it is smart.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with no loops (recursive)

```
public class NumberTriangle {        

    public static void print(int top_, int count_, int length_) {
        int top = top_;
        int count = count_;
        int length = length_;
        count++;        

        if (count <= top){
            length++;           
        } else {
            length--;
        }

        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }       

        String s = String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", length), 0).replace("0",""+count);     
        System.out.println(s);

        NumberTriangle.print(top, count, length);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){

        NumberTriangle.print(5,0,0);

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution for the problem:

```
IntStream.range(MAX * -1, MAX)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX - Math.abs(i))
                    .mapToObj(j -> j == MAX - Math.abs(i) ? MAX - Math.abs(i) + "\n" : MAX - Math.abs(i) + " ")
                    .forEach(System.out::print)
            );
```

Answer (score -1):

@RandMate you could do it this way:
    to print this pattern you will have to divide the pattern into 2 parts and use
    two sets of nested for loop:
    here goes:
     int i,j,p;
     /*first nested loop to print
      1
      22
      333
      4444
      55555*/
     for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {
      for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
      {
       System.out.print(i);
      }
      System.out.println();
     }

```
/*this is the second nested loop to print
 6666
 777
 88
 9 */
    p=6;
  for(i=4;i>=1;i--)
  {
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
   {
    System.out.print(p);
   }
    p=p+1;
   System.out.println();
  }

  Hope it was helpul.
  ALL THE BEST......enjoy!
```